# Excel formula to search two cells for string and multiply corresponding numbers if string is different

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to compare two specific cells that each contain a single string.  The string consists of a numerical value, of one or two digits, followed by the letter `H` or `W`. Or the cell could contain just a zero (with no letter). 
e.g., Cells could contain `3H` or `2W` or `0`.

I want to output a value in a third cell based on these two cells.  If the cells both end in the same letter, I want the formula to output the value zero (0). If they end with different letters, I want the formula to multiply the numerical values from the two cells.  If either cell contains just a zero, the output value should be zero.

Examples:

- `3H` compared against `2W` becomes `3 x 2`, outputting `6`.
- `3H` compared against `2H` outputs `0` because the letters match.
- `3H` compared against `0` outputs `0` because one of the values is `0`.

In the worksheet, the numerical values are variable (up to `99`), but the letters will only ever be `H` or `W` and will always be immediately after the number (except in the case of a `0` entry).

Comment: Can the numeric portion be any number of digits?  Can we assume you aren't interested in suggestions to put the text in a neighboring cell?  Is the letter guaranteed to be the right-most character (e.g., no case where there's a space after the letter)?  Is there always a letter or could you have an entry with just a number?

Comment: The value will be a maximum of 99, so either 1 or 2 digits long. For computational and layout reasons I need the number and string to remain together in a single cell. Yes the letter is always guaranteed to be the right-most character and the only entry with just a number will be a zero.

Comment: If one of the cells can contain just a zero, what do you do with that?

Comment: Essentially multiply the zero, or just simply output zero.

Comment: Seems simple enough. Have you written it out in pseudo code? For example, if - or (a2=0, b2=0) : output 0, resume with another question if.

Comment: I read in detail, but there remains a big hole in the algorithm to solve this. Zero is an option. What is the largest number that a cell could contain and must the number have a letter attached to it? Could it be 1000 say by itself, or 10 or 10W, or 10R. This is an important concept. Another thing is that each cell is to contain a string or characters of all numbers and/or numbers mixed with letters. Will the letter always be at the end of the string? Please write this in your question to explicitly define the contents of a cell as it changes the methods used to solve the question.

Comment: @ejbytes, good questions.  I think we got them covered previously in comments.  I took your edits a little farther to make things even more explicit.  Some of these points were teased out as we were working on a solution.  But you're right, it should all be clearly rolled into the question so that it's useful to others.  See if you think this version is bulletproof.

Comment: @fixer1234 Looks solid! I had reviewed this in the "review" functionality of this website and dint' realize that this was already answered. Have a great one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your two values are in cells A1 and B1 and your result is going in C1.  You could use this in C1:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)=RIGHT(B1,1),0,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*LEFT(B1,LEN(B1)-1))
```

This assumes there are no irregularities, like an errant space anywhere.  It compares the right-most character of the two cells and returns zero if they match.  Otherwise, it multiplies everything except the right-most character.  Extracting everything to the left of the right-most character gives you a text string, but Excel is smart enough to treat it like a number.

You indicate in a comment that one of the values could be a lone zero (no character following), in which case the output should be zero.  To avoid an error condition, you need to handle such a cell, which you could do by including a test.  This method will also handle a blank cell:

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(A1,1)=RIGHT(B1,1),A1=0,B1=0),0,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*LEFT(B1,LEN(B1)-1))
```

Comment: It's handling the zeros correctly, but giving #Value error for any numerical value multiplied... Any ideas?

Comment: @zenmonki, you're right.  I needed more coffee.  Try the revised formula.

Comment: @zenmonki, if the revised formula gives you an error on values containing a normal entry (number followed by letter), verify that you don't have a leading or trailing space.  A problem with mixing numbers and letters in cells on which you want to do math is that it can hide all kinds of anomalies that need to be cleaned up or handled, and the formulas can quickly go from something trivial to something complicated.

Comment: Thanks and understood. Right now excel is just outputting zeros for everything. Am I missing something still?

Comment: I tested this and it worked, so my guess would be problems with the data.  Did you copy and paste the formula?  If not, verify that you don't have typos.  If you're getting zero, it means one or more of the three conditions the IF is testing for is true.  Try manually entering some values to ensure it works with just digits followed by a letter and there are no extraneous characters.  Another diagnostic: enter just the pieces of the formula as a formula to see what they are producing (e.g., =RIGHT(A!,1), =LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1), etc.)

Comment: Right my mistake, it's not outputting zeros, but it is giving a #Value! error for anything other than a zero. No leading or trailing spaces... The worked on cells come from a previous formula, but I can't understand this being an issue right?

Comment: First step is to figure out if the issue is with the data for the formula.  Manually enter 3H and 2W, so you know those are the only characters in the cells, and see if the formula works.

Comment: Another thought: there's no space between the digits and the letter?  If the formula that produces the cell contents isn't insanely long, it might be helpful to post it in a comment.

Comment: With a bit of additional help, I realised that when you compare a cell using = operator you are actually comparing the formula string instead of the result. Instead you need to use EXACT

E.G. =IF(OR(RIGHT(G1,1)=RIGHT(CM1,1),EXACT(G1,0),EXACT(CM1,0)),0,LEFT(G1,LEN(G1)-1)*LEFT(CM1,LEN(CM1)-1))

Comment: "=" compares the cell result, not the formula.  EXACT is like a qualifier.  Just using "=" will find some things equivalent if they aren't precisely the same (like upper vs. lower case).  That's what lets you use G1=0 to return a true if the cell is empty.  Using EXACT will return true only if they're identical, so a blank cell should produce an error with your formula.  Strange that you needed that to get this to work (you should not have gotten a #VALUE with the original formula).  Something odd is going on.  But glad you got a working solution.

Comment: The solution accepted, but problematic? I cleaned up some of the question awaiting review without knowing a solution was accepted. For me the question that was being begged: What is the minimum amount of characters in a comparison? Maximum? Also, is the last character always a letter? Are these acceptable strings, "0", "10W", "100H", "1", "10", "100", "24", "24H"... The answers to these fundamental questions are rudimentary in the solution.

Comment: @ejbytes, see if all of the potential questions are covered, now.  I'm scratching my head on this one as far as the solution.  Once the issues were clarified, it was straightforward, and the solution worked for my examples without a problem.  However, zenmonki ran into some odd problems that I couldn't replicate.  He found a modification to the solution (a few comments up), that solved his problem, but I can't see why that would be the case, either.  I'm just guessing there is some characteristic of his spreadsheet that hasn't been described and may not be obvious.

Comment: @ejbytes, thanks for taking a look. To answer your questions as best I can: Min number of characters is 1. E.G. "0". If not zero then min number of characters is 2. The last character is always a letter from a previous "&" operator, except in the case of "0". Acceptable strings are "0", "10W", "100H", "24H". Fixer1234, thanks for the solution. EXACT was necessary to avoid #Value! errors from a number of previous nested formulas. I think when you were testing you just input the characters directly in the cell, rather than pulling them in from elsewhere... I hope this helps clarify the situation

Comment: @ejbytes, ...Oh and max number of characters is 3. E.G "99H". Thanks again.

Comment: @zenmonki Thanks for chiming in. Glad it all worked out.